# (i.i.d) Random sampling assumption in practical situations

Tags: normal-distribution, inference, assumptions, survey-sampling

This is a practical question.

Assume that there are two finite populations X and Y in the real world. For example, we want to compare $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$. We can use a probability sampling scheme such as stratified sampling or simple random sampling without replacement to extract two samples from the population X and Y. Of course, the two samples are extracted from two finite populations. Then we can estimate $\bar{Y}- \bar{X}$ by $\bar{y}- \bar{x}$ without making additional assumptions.

The sampling distribution of $\bar{y}- \bar{x}$ will probably not be Gaussian given finite populations and a specific sampling scheme (approximately Gaussian if the sample sizes are large?). Given a specific sampling scheme, there are probably specific testing procedures for the equality of means.

Although the two samples are extracted from two finite populations (e.g. X: Heights of American citizens and Y: Heights of Canadian citizens) using a specfic *(finite-population*) sampling scheme, however, in practice, no matter what the **known** probabilistic sampling scheme is, I often assume that the first sample $x_i$ are realizations from i.i.d Gausssian random variables  $X_i$, for example, and $y_i$ (i = 1,2,3,...n) are realizations from i.i.d Gaussian random variables $Y_i$ (i = 1,2,3,...m). Then I can proceed with t-test as usual.

*Let's assume here that histograms of X and Y resemble "bell-shaped" curve.*

It is something that I always take for granted. However, I want to know if it is something that statisticans often do in practice (i.e. by assuming that the sampling scheme is random sampling from i.i.d random samples regardless of the **true sampling scheme/finiteness of the population**). Is it an appropriate procedure?

Comment: Please edit the question if you want. I type the question at midnight, so it could be unclear.

Comment: Assuming you are sampling Americans and Canadians each at random, the height distributions may not be normally distributed (e.g. they might have two peaks related to gender, or a long left tail for children) but the sample means may have approximately normal distributions for large enough sample sizes thanks to the central limit theorem.  It is the distributions of the means and of the difference between means which justifies your test.  Assuming your sample sizes are not most of the populations, having the populations finite is not going to be a substantial issue